# ContentVersion.VersionData or ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData doesn't return the base64 body

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, contentversion, sfdcmobilesdk-android

We're using mobile SDK and want to retrieve the SOUP of ContentVersion bodies(VersionData) to be able to generate the images when our users are in offline mode.
According to the [documentation about the ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) when we're querying the following info:
`SELECT VersionData, ContentDocumentId  FROM ContentVersion  WHERE isLatest=true`
We should recieve the base64 file's body inside the VersionData field, but in reality it returns just the link to the VersionData in the following format: `/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/....attachId.../VersionData.` Trying to run the same SOQL from Salesforce Developer Console returns the same result.

Because the ContentVersion object has some sharing and querying limitations, we've decided to change our query to the following one:

```
SELECT LinkedEntityId,
 ContentDocument.Title,
 ContentDocument.Description,
 ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData
 FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN ( SELECT Id FROM ..ourObjectName...)
```

In this case `ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData` returns Blob object(from what I've read with Binary data inside) if its queried from Anonymous Debug Window.
[image: Anonymous window query result]
If it's queried from the Workbench it returns base64 encoded body.
[image: query from Workbench]

BUT when we're trying to query it using Mobile SDK, the `ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData` returns us link again.

[image: query usnig Mobile SDK]

**So I have the following questions:**

1. Why does ContentVersion.VersionData doesn't return the base64 encoded body but link both to Mobile and to SF?
2. Why does ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData returns binary encoded Blob object when querying form Anonymous debug window, base64 encoded - when querying from Workbench, and LINK when querying it from mobile?
3. Is there any way to retrieve base64/Binary encoded Blob body when querying VersionData using MobileSDK(directly, without shooting to the SF endpoint)?
4. If not, maybe you have some ideas how to retrieve it in the above mentioned formats?

Because our App already does a lot of functionality/calculations on Mobile side + we want to make it working in offline mode, additional REST requests to SF to receive VersionData is **very unwanted**.

P.S. when shooting to the endpoint the VersionData returns, it returns Binary encoded data, but not base64 still.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I have the same question - why can we not see the VersionData in the Developer Console?